# Getting started with wicket andHibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, wicket

Im new to Wicket and Hibernate. I have watched the youtube videos and read som chapters about Hibernate. I still have a question that I need to know before Im able to use Hibernate:

In wicket we have Application.java (for all the common things) and a java file for eache "page" in the application, for instance login.java, register.java etc. What should go in Application.java and what is good programming practise when using Hibernate in Wicket?

All the examples I have seen is ither with other frameworks like Wicket togheter with Spring or examples using just one file, the Application.java fil. Gess Im comfused and really miss an example using at least Application.java, one class file and one .java file for som function like saving forms, retriving db etc..

I dont know if its important, but Im using Netbeans in this project.

Any tips welcome

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best way is to keep the persistence layer away from the presentation layer (in order to achieve a clean MVC architecture).

In this case this means you should put your Wicket related initialization logic in your Application class (more specifically [WebApplication](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.html), since you are discouraged from subclassing [Application](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/Application.html) directly) and put the persistence related logic in your DAO-s (preferably well encapsulated in a service layer).

You can find more information about the DAO pattern in the [DAO Pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) and about transaction based persistence with Wicket, Spring and Hibernate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531451/three-tier-layered-application-using-wicket-spring-hibernate-how-would-you)

Comment: I do have som examples using Wicket-Spring-Hibernate. I did read them, but they seamed a lot different than the examples without Spring.

Comment: Will Spring make the application "fat"? Would it be overkill to use it on a project that has maby 10 small pages? Will I need to know a lot about Spring, and will it pay of later? It might be wise to use spring, but so far I havent seen any argument to why...

Comment: It will not, since version 3.0 Spring is greatly modularized, thus allowing you to keep your application "slim" :) I recommend learning Spring (at least the basics) because it has solution to the most everyday tasks and it is still quite easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You should create DAO - class with main functions (geting, saving, updating objects) and create instance in WebApplication class. For example you have:

```
public class WebApp extends WebApplication {

    private final MyDAO myDAO = new MyDAO();
    public MyDAO getMyDAO() {
       return myDAO;
    }
    init(){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and in page classes you can get this instance using

```
  ((WebApp)Application.get()).getMyDAO()
```

P.S.

And please, don't use additional component.. only hibernate + wicket. I Agree with Paarth, if you don't know wicket and hibernate you should start from tiny test project for wicket and for hibernate

Comment: Using a DAO - class file make sence, since it makes it easy to reuse the DAO class in other applications. If I understand this correctly, I should make one object i Application.java and then pass the refference to this object to any pages that needs to use it. Makes sence when I think about it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when you are new to both Hibernaet & Wicket, try learning one after another.

Make some demo/POC project for Hibernate with Simple Java program.
Then go on Wicket, make some demo on that also.

Then make some small web application, integrating Hibernate and Wicket together as you have learned.

You should be going easy, thoroughly.

Hibernate should be pretty easy if your OOP concepts are clear. I don't have idea about Wicket, so can't say on it.

Comment: Yes, its wise to breake thing apart and study it bit by bit. Ive been playing around with Wicket for a while, so I started to build an application who would use forms and tables to store and retrive information from a db. The consepts seems clear, and Hibernate has a lot of resources to look into when stuck. It just missed to inform about what to program where when using more than one page. I have found wicket-spring-hibernate examples, and will try to figure out from them wich klines of code goes where :-)

Answer (score 0):

For implementing Wicket with Hibernate, take a look at Databinder (http://github.com/n8han/Databinder-for-Wicket/). It is an excellent, thin layer between Wicket and Hibernate (among other data handlers).

However, Databinder's core was written for something like Wicket 1.2 and hasn't been updated in quite some time.  Several people say they're going to update it (including myself) and they haven't.

So, Databinder is a great model of how to use Wicket and Hibernate.  However, in practice, it has several flaws that need to be addressed.

For a quick fix, check out Databinder version 1.3.2.CAST at http://comp.cast.org/maven2/ which at least brings Databinder in line with the latest Hibernate.

For a complex and incomplete, but powerful, implementation of this code, see http://code.google.com/p/cast-wicket-modules/

For a completed project that uses those modules, see https://code.google.com/p/udl-curriculum-toolkit/

All of those links are works in progress, but a place to start.